# Why does adding comment in docker file throws error

Tags: docker

I am newbie in docker and I created below docker file and it works fine.

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2 as base
SHELL ["powershell"]
ENV ENABLE_IIS_CONSOLE_LOGGING=1
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; `
Import-Module ServerManager -Force; `
```

But as soon as I add a comment on top

```
# This is a comment line
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2 as base
SHELL ["powershell"]
ENV ENABLE_IIS_CONSOLE_LOGGING=1
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; `
Import-Module ServerManager -Force; `
```

I start getting **red squiggly** in VS Code.

[image: No IRed Squiggly]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is not a comment, it is a parser directive:

```
# escape=`
```

However, a parser directive must come at the top of the Dockerfile, before any other comments, `FROM` steps, `ARG` variables, etc. If you place a comment before it, docker stops looking for parser directives and you no longer modify the escape character which defaults to `\`.

For more details on parser directives, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#parser-directives

Comment: What is the benefit of having parser directive in docker file?

Comment: It gives the ability to change how it parses the Dockerfile, in this case changing the escape character since windows environments tend to use \ for something different than an escape character.